# How to run WordPress from other location on the same domain

Tags: themes, installation, wp-config, subdomains

Hi I have a domain running in WordPress,

the path to WordPress installation is `/subdomain/mywordpress/` and I can access these in `mywordpress.mysite.com`, Now I wish to load the index page on my main domain, ie

When I goto `mysite.com` I want to load the Index page of the WordPress, I know if that possible, the links are always pointing to `mywordpress.mysite.com`, but that is what I need know. because I dont want to remove the `mywordpress.mysite.com`. I just need to display all posts on my main site, with same design(that is why I prefer to load the Index file of wordpress)

Comment: why not just move it to the main domain?

Answer (score 1):

While this is possible using htaccess directives or mod_proxy on your server side, WordPress doesn't like unexpected requests and will cause you all kinds of problems. Scripts are not designed to run across sites either. 
If you want to display all your posts on your main domain you need to move your WordPress instance over to the main domain.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress